# Open an secure web page with php curl

Tags: php, security, ssl, curl

I would like to open the following websites (which use a secure connection) using PHP Curl:

```
$url = "www.missjoias.com.br";
$url = "www.perfumes.com.br";
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$handle=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
//curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/ca-bundle.crt.txt");
$content = curl_exec($handle);
echo $content; // show target page
exit;

?>
```

The line with ca-bundle.crt.txt  is commented but I have tried with and without it.
I always get a http 403 Forbidden access response.
Any help?

Comment: put the urls in your browser and see what you get.

Comment: It is ok with browsers, but I need to crawl pages with curl or other function that returns the html code

Comment: i get a 403 with browser perhaps they are blocking countries? is your web host in the same country as you?

Comment: Humm!! I think the server might be blocking IP. It is in Brazil just like me. I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're getting a 403, it means the certificates are working fine and the server is blocking for one reasons or another.  Could be due to IP address or some headers are missing from the request that they want to see (e.g. Accept, User-Agent [which you have]).

Comment: I will try to open pages from another ip address. Thanks.